# Why $ \dfrac{d}{dx} f(kx) = kf'(kx) $?

Tags: calculus

In MIT OCW 18.01 Single variable calculus [lecture 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9v25gg2qJYE), minute 18:00-18:20, the professor used an example to explain why $e$ exists.

Context:

$f(x) = 2^x$
$b=2^k$
$ f(kx)=2^{kx} = (2^k)^x $

Then the professor wrote this, that by chain rule: $$ \dfrac{d}{dx} f(kx) = kf'(kx) $$

Why does it work? Why need to add additional $k$ there? 
If I expand derivative of $f(x)$ as: $$ \dfrac{d}{dx}f(x) = 2^x\dfrac{(2^{\Delta x} - 1)}{\Delta x} $$ then derivative of $f(kx)$ should be:

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx}f(kx) = f'(kx) = 2^{kx}\dfrac{(2^{\Delta x} - 1)}{\Delta x} $$

Even if it's typo where Professor intended to write: $\dfrac{d}{dx}f(kx) = kf'(x) $ I don't think that it will work either. 
Because

$$ k 2^{x}\dfrac{(2^{\Delta x} - 1)}{\Delta x} \ne  2^{kx}\dfrac{(2^{\Delta x} - 1)}{\Delta x} $$
right?

Comment: Slight mistake: $$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(kx) = f'(kx) = 2^{kx}\dfrac{(2^{k\Delta x} - 1)}{\Delta x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f(kx)=2^{kx}$, then derivative for $x$ is
$$\frac{df}{dx}(kx)=f'(kx)\cdot k$$

Because if you let $g(x)=kx$, then
$$\frac{df}{dx}(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
which is the chain rule.

Comment: Now that I see $k$ is just function to multiply $x$ instead of $x^k$, it's much more understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A general differentiable $f$ satisfies $$\dfrac{d}{dx}f(kx)=\underbrace{\dfrac{d(kx)}{dx}}_k\underbrace{\dfrac{d}{d(kx)}f(kx)}_{f^\prime(kx)}.$$